# 32-bit colored icons not available on Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, visual-studio, 32-bit

I want to add an icon to my project and the icon is working, but Visual Studio (I've tried both 2019 and 2022) won't let me use 32-bit colors to create an icon. The icon editing tools are greyed out on all 32-bit icons regardless of the size.

The reason why I'm asking this question is because when I compile my code, it ends up with the default icon instead of my custom icon, even when I've removed all 32-bit configurations.

There are no error messages when I build as well.

32-bit color icons have been working fine until I did a clean reinstall of Windows 10.

I'm running Windows 10 x64, version 20H2.

My project is in C++ 20 with toolset of v142.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework are you targeting? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/ux-guidelines/images-and-icons-for-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) it’s due the project type.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I'm still relatively new to Visual Studio. How do I check? All I know is that I'm using v142 platform toolset.